# JFrog Xray xray-env.cnf

Tags: configuration, config, jfrog-xray

The documentation for XRay says you can use the xray-env.cnf file for automated scripting of deployment but I can't find it on the fielsystem and don't know where precisely it is supposed to be placed.

Where does this file belong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file should be placed in /var/opt/jfrog/xray/scripts.